# Drawing to canvas while in loop

Tags: android-canvas, android

In Eclipse IDE for Android I am fighting with one simple problem right now.
I am using code like this:

```
public class Reader extends Activity 
{
    // declarations
    private class GraphView extends View 
    {
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        {
            synchronized(this)
            {
                final Paint paint = mPaint;
                // some drawings
                myvoid(canvas,paint);
                // some drawings
            }
        }
    }
    void myvoid(Canvas c,Paint p)
    {
        int i=0;
        do //or for cycle
        {
            i++;
            c.drawText(Integer.toString(i),0,100,p); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Problem
        }
        while (i<100000);
    }
}
```

The canvas and text is not updating,until the while loop is finished.
It seems,that the canvas is "locked" during that time.
How can I achieve,that I can see the progress inside of the loop on the canvas?

Thanks,Tomas.

Comment: Use multi-threading for it.

Comment: Are you performing this loop on the main/UI thread?

Comment: can you post the complete code for your View

Comment: Sorry,new here and not as skilled developer as it seems. How to post the full code here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not giving any time for Android to present the results of the drawing method. You should draw one step of the loop and call invalidate to trigger next step. Android will draw your text on the screen and then it will try to redraw it with increased counter once again. Please compare your code and my version:

```
private class GraphView extends View {

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { // some drawings
        myvoid(canvas, paint);
        // some drawings
    }

    void myvoid(Canvas c, Paint p) {
        int i = 0;
        do // or for cycle
        {
            i++;
            c.drawText(Integer.toString(i), 0, 100, p);
        } while (i < 100000);
    }
}
```

My version with invalidate():

```
private class GraphView extends View {
    int i = 0;
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(i), 0, 100, paint);
        i++;
        invalidate();
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: i++ is just an example. I have inside of the do-while loop lot of other things. I know,your example works just fine. I want to give the time to draw,even tough the loop will take a bit longer time. Is there any hidden hint,that forces the canvas to redraw each time?

Comment: Of course it's an example. Each time you want to show something new on the screen, you have to leave draw() method. Android will pass the result of your draw() onto screen. And, if draw() contains invalidate(), Android will try to refresh the view in the following animation frame.

Comment: Okay,that makes sense. However,this same happens even I am running loop inside of draw().

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        //float dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
       // float dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

You can try to make your canvas a bitmap image then set bitmap to your imageview

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps :

- set the view in the activity
- start a secondary thread to do your process
- in the thread invalidate the view

this example maybe helps : https://github.com/hamilton-lima/Bolinha/tree/master/src/com/example/bolinha